# How to restart a sketch project in processing?

Tags: processing

I am working on a Processing project, but I don´t know how to restart the project once it is over. I have searched and found that the `setup()` method will make it. But it's not working. Can anyone help me. I would like the sketch to restart by itself once it is finished.

```java
    /* OpenProcessing Tweak of *@*http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/59807*@* */
/* !do not delete the line above, required for linking your tweak if you upload again */
//
// outline: takes an image (image.jpg) and creates a sketch version
//
// procsilas (procsilas@hotmail.com / http://procsilas.net)
//

String iName="image.jpeg";

void setup() {
  llegeixImatge("./"+iName);
  size(img.width, img.height);
}

// parameters
// NO real control, so be careful

int NP=6000; // 1000 for line art, 10000 for complex images, O(N^2) so be patient!!!
int B=1; // try 2 or 3
float THR=28; // range 5-50
float MD=6; // range 0-10
int NMP=6; // range 1-15

float[][] punts;
color[] cpunts;
int [] usat;
int [] NmP=new int[NMP];
float [] NdmP=new float[NMP];

int inici=0;

PImage img;

void llegeixImatge(String s) {
  img = loadImage(s);
  img.loadPixels();
}

float fVar(int x, int y) {
  // neighborhood 2B+1x2B+1 pixels
  float m=0;
  for (int k1=-B; k1<=B; k1++) {
    for (int k2=-B; k2<=B; k2++) {
      color c=img.pixels[(y+k1)*img.width+(x+k2)];
      m+=brightness(c);
    }
  }
  m/=float((2*B+1)*(2*B+1));
  float v=0;
  for (int k1=-B; k1<B; k1++) {
    for (int k2=-B; k2<B; k2++) {
      color c=img.pixels[(y+k1)*img.width+(x+k2)];
      v+=(brightness(c)-m)*(brightness(c)-m);
    }
  }
  v=sqrt(v)/(float) (2*B+1);    

  return v;
}

void creaPunts() {
  punts = new float[NP][2];
  cpunts = new color[NP];
  usat = new int[NP];

  int nint1=0;
  int nint2=0;

  for (int i=0; i<NP;) {

    int x=B+int(random(width-2*B));
    int y=B+int(random(height-2*B));

    //println(i+" = "+x+", "+y+": "+THR+", "+MD);

    // points need to be at least MD far from each other
    int flag=0;
    if (MD>0.0) {  
      for (int j=0; flag==0 && j<i; j++) {
        if (dist(x, y, punts[j][0], punts[j][1])<MD) {
          flag=1;
        }
      }
    }

    if (flag==0) { 
      nint1=0;
      float f=fVar(x, y);

      // use only "valid" points      
      if (f>=THR) {
        nint2=0;
        punts[i][0]=x;
        punts[i][1]=y;
        cpunts[i]=img.pixels[y*img.width+x];
        usat[i]=0;
        i++;
      } 
      else {
        nint2++;
        if (nint2>=10) {
          THR/=(1+1.0/float(NP-i));
          MD/=(1+1.0/float(NP-i));
          nint2=0;
        }
      }
    } 
    else {
      nint1++;
      if (nint1>=10) {
        MD/=2.0;
        THR*=1.618;
        nint1=0;
      }
    }
  }
}

int NessimMesProper(int i) {
  if (NMP<=1) {
    int mP=-1;
    float dmP=dist(0, 0, width, height);
    for (int j=0; j<NP; j++) {
      if (usat[j]==0) {
        float jmP=dist(punts[i][0], punts[i][1], punts[j][0], punts[j][1]);
        if (jmP<dmP) {
          dmP=jmP;
          mP=j;
        }
      }
    }
    return mP;
  } 
  else {
    for (int j=0; j<NMP; j++) {
      NmP[j]=-1;    
      NdmP[j]=dist(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    for (int j=0; j<NP; j++) {
      if (usat[j]==0) {
        float jmP=dist(punts[i][0], punts[i][1], punts[j][0], punts[j][1]);
        int k=NMP;
        while(k>0 && NdmP[k-1]>jmP) {
          k--;
        }
        if (k<NMP) {
          for (int l=0; l<(NMP-k)-1; l++) {
            NmP[(NMP-1)-l]=NmP[(NMP-1)-(l+1)];
            NdmP[(NMP-1)-l]=NdmP[(NMP-1)-(l+1)];
          }
          NmP[k]=j;
          NdmP[k]=jmP;
        }
      }
    }
    return NmP[NMP-1];
  }
}

int fase=0;

void draw() {
  if (fase==0) {
    creaPunts();
    background(#FFFFFF);
    fase=1;
  } 
  else {
    if (inici!=-1) {
      stroke(#000000);
      usat[inici]=1;

      int seguent=NessimMesProper(inici);
      if (seguent!=-1) {
        line(punts[inici][0], punts[inici][1], punts[seguent][0], punts[seguent][1]);
      }
      inici=seguent;
    } 
    else {
      //save("outline_"+iName);


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a site where questions and answers that can help all are presented. In order for this question to help future users we ask that you post **all** pertinent information here with your question and not in links. Also, please understand that all who help here are volunteers, and we much appreciate your making it as easy as possible to understand your question, including not making us go to outside sites for information. So please post all code here with your question.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A program trying to relaunch itself on `exit()` could cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Java tag removed as that's not Java code that you're posting.

Comment: The code makes a outline of a selected image and yes i am trying a infinite loop after the image is created. I have tried with setup() and exit() but does not make the desired effect. setup() does not make anything and exit() closes the java program.

Comment: draw should loop infinitely for you - if it isn't, you're making a mistaken somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** call `setup()` yourself.

**Step 1:** Encapsulate the state of your program in a set of variables.

**Step 2:** Use those variables to draw your sketch.

**Step 3:** Modify those variables to change what's being drawn.

**Step 4:** Simply reset those variables to their initial values when you want to reset the sketch.

Here's an example program that stores its state (the positions the user has clicked) in an `ArrayList`. It uses that `ArrayList` to draw the sketch, and new points are added whenever the user clicks. When the user types a key, the sketch is reset by clearing out the `ArrayList`:

```java
ArrayList<PVector> points = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  for(PVector p : points){
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  points.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}

void keyPressed(){
 points.clear(); 
}
```