# Drawing New Circles at click location while saving previous ones

Tags: java, processing

Hi I want to draw new circles when I enter new radius for them and click button. I am supposed to position it with mouse. However after I draw circle I either can't draw new one or i can't position it mouse too.

```
import interfascia.*;

int numCircles = 500;
Circle[] circles = new Circle[numCircles]; // define the array
int k=0;
GUIController c;
IFButton b1;
IFTextField tn;
float bx;
float by;
boolean overBox = false;
boolean locked = false;
float xOffset = 0.0; 
float yOffset = 0.0; 
float r;


void setup() {
  size(1439,800);
  smooth();
  noStroke();

  bx=width/2;
  by=height/2;

   c = new GUIController (this);
  b1 = new IFButton ("Click to draw", 600, 220, 100);
  tn=new IFTextField("", 100,20,50);

  c.add(b1);
  c.add(tn);

}

void draw() {
  background(205);
  if (mouseX > bx-r && mouseX < bx+r && 
      mouseY > by-r && mouseY < by+r) {
    overBox = true;  
    if(!locked) {           
    } 
  } else {

    overBox = false;
  }
    circles[k] = new Circle(bx,by,r);
    circles[k].display(); // display all the circles

}

void actionPerformed (GUIEvent e) {
 if (e.getSource() == b1) {
      r=float(tn.getValue());

  } 

}

class Circle {
  float x,y,r; // location

  color c; // color

  Circle(float x, float y, float r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;

    c = color(random(255));
  }

  void display() {

    ellipse(x,y,10,10); // a circle at position xy
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if(overBox) { 
    locked = true; 

  } else {
    locked = false;
  }
  xOffset = mouseX-bx; 
  yOffset = mouseY-by;     
}

void mouseDragged() {
  if(locked) {
    bx = mouseX-xOffset; 
    by = mouseY-yOffset;        
  }
}    

void mouseReleased() {
  locked = false;
  overBox=false;     
}
```

Comment: Don't clear the screen simply.

Comment: Please, can you edit you code snippet with maintainable variable names ?

Comment: Hint: the law prohibiting to use more than one character for variable names was well, never written. Simply dont do that.

Comment: I can see a class called `Circle`. Outside of it, there are methods and variables. They have to be in another class. What is that? It looks like Circle is a nested class in the outer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main options:

**Option 1:** Stop calling the `background()` function from your `draw()` function. This is what's clearing out old frames. If you remove that (or move it to `setup()`, then your old frames will never be cleared out.

**Option 2:** Store your *state* in a set of data structures. You can think of using arrays to store the position and radius of each of your circles. (Or better yet, create a `Circle` class and store it instances of that in an `ArrayList`.) Then to draw your scene, just iterate over your data structure and draw all of your circles.

Another option is to use an off-screen `PGraphics` buffer.

Comment: I've edited my code and add Circle class but it still doesn't work

Comment: @dummy You don't ever seem to change the `k` variable. And you're still only ever drawing a single circle. You have to iterate over the array to draw all the circles. Also your code would be easier to run if you posted a [mcve] without any of the GUI builder stuff.

Comment: @dummy Please see this post for an example that uses an `ArrayList` of `Circle` objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691263/how-to-restart-a-sketch-project-in-processing

Comment: I've added iteration in actionPerformed however it didn't work I don;t know where to add iteration

Comment: @dummy Think about what you're trying to do. Whenever you want to draw multiple circles, you'll have to iterate over the array that holds your circle data.

Comment: `ArrayList<PVector> points = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  for(PVector p : points){
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  points.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}

void keyPressed(){
 points.clear(); 
}`

Comment: how can I position points with dragging them around in this code?

Comment: @dummy This isn't really how Stack Overflow works. You're going to have to try something and post a new question if you get stuck. But basically you're going to have to add code that detects when you click inside a circle. You could do this by iterating over every circle and checking the distance between the mouse position and the circle position.